# Wrong login redirect after manually installing OpenStack Horizon

Tags: openstack, horizon

I'm trying to install `OpenStac`k dashboard (Horizon) manually using the documentation guide on `CentOS 8`. I have followed the rules and started the httpd service. But, when I access the dashboard from the browser, it directs me to "`http://IP/auth/login`" page, which doesn't exist. The correct URL should be "`http://IP/dashboard/auth/login`". When I try to append the missing "dashboard", it directs me to the login form, but it looks like the

Horizon login form without `css`
[image: horizon login form without css]

And when I enter my credentials, it can't validate them. However, the URL of keystone is provided to `/etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings` file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding the following three lines to '/etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings'

```
WEBROOT = '/dashboard/'
LOGIN_URL = '/dashboard/auth/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/dashboard/auth/logout/'
```